# Triangles that can be cut into mutually congruent and non-convex polygons

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, tiling, triangles

It is easy to note that an equilateral triangle can be cut into 3 mutually congruent and non-convex polygons *(replace the 3 lines meeting at centroid and separating out the 3 congruent quadrilaterals with identical polylines to get 3 congruent, non-convex pieces)* and this partition is easily generalized to 12, 27, ... number of pieces.

***Question***: Are there other triangles that can be cut into N polygons that are ***non-convex*** and mutually congruent? If so, for what values of N?

***Note 1***: I don't know if there is any partition of any triangle into 7 mutually congruent polygons, convex or otherwise - although it has been proved (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.09723.pdf) that no triangle can be cut into 7 or 11 ***congruent triangles***.

***Note 2***: It is known that there are convex polygons that can be cut into a finite number of non-convex and mutually congruent pieces but NOT into convex congruent pieces (eg: [A claim on partitioning a convex planar region into congruent pieces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370302/a-claim-on-partitioning-a-convex-planar-region-into-congruent-pieces)).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with $24$ pieces:

[image]

In general proving impossibility results will be extremely hard, as it is with almost all tiling problems of this form.

Comment: Thanks. Nice construction with the sphinx that you had put up here as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953136/which-equilateral-triangles-does-the-p-hexiamond-the-sphinx-tile . The triangle being tiled is again equilateral. Perhaps no other triangle admits a tiling by any number of non-convex tiles. It might be easier to prove that no triangle with all sides different has this property.

Comment: Indeed, one would be surprised if equilaterals are the only triangles that can be tiled by non-convex tiles.