# On partitioning convex planar regions into congruent pieces - 2

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, tiling

We add a bit to [A claim on partitioning a convex planar region into congruent pieces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370302/a-claim-on-partitioning-a-convex-planar-region-into-congruent-pieces) .

**Definition:** A perfect congruent partition of a planar region $C$ is a partition of it into some finite number $n$ of pieces that are all mutually congruent (any piece can be transformed into another piece by an isometry. We consider only cases where each piece is connected and is bounded by a simple curve) and with no part of $C$ left out (not part of any piece).

**Question:** If from a convex planar region $C$, $2$ connected, mutually congruent pieces (pieces need not be convex) can be cut such that no point of the boundary of $C$ is left out, then will $C$ always allow a perfect congruent partition into $2$ pieces (with no point on the entire $C$ left out)? I can't think of a counterexample or proof.

**Note:** The question can be generalized from $2$ pieces to $n$ pieces.

**An extension:** If the answer to above question is "yes", can one say: "if one is looking for a partition of any planar convex region $C$ into n mutually congruent connected pieces that *leave out the least fraction of the area of $C$*, is it enough to look among congruent partitions that together leave out the least fraction of the *boundary* of $C$"?

**Note added on April 20th, 2023:** It was found after some experimentation that for values of n >=5, the answer to the above question is "not necessarily" (http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/04/another-question-on-congruent-partitions.html). The remaining cases are n = 2,3,4.