# An algorithm to decide whether a convex polygon can be cut into 2 mutually congruent pieces

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

This post is based on the answer to this question: [A claim on partitioning a convex planar region into congruent pieces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370302/a-claim-on-partitioning-a-convex-planar-region-into-congruent-pieces)

A *perfect congruent partition* of a planar region is a partition of it with no portion left over into some finite number *n* of pieces that are all mutually congruent. The answer from above post shows how to construct a convex polygon with *odd number of edges* that can be perfect congruent partitioned into 2 non-convex pieces but not into 2 convex pieces.

**Question:** Given an n-vertex convex polygon *P*, how does one algorithmically decide if it has a perfect congruent partition into 2 pieces - and find a dividing line/polyline if one exists? Can an algorithm linear in *n* be found? Is the convexity of *P* important?

If *n* is odd, one end of the partitioning line/polyline has to be at a vertex of *P*. Not sure about the *n* even case. One suspects that increasing the number of mutually congruent pieces even from 2 to 3 could make things very difficult.

An old, related blog post: https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2009/05/identical-partitions-of-polygons.html